# Freedom from cycle of ( re-birth _ death_re-birth )

Tags: consciousness

Is the re-birth recurrence principle a belief or an assumption proved true by those more spiritually evolved in states of higher consciousness? Were there instances of verification or revelations in ancient or in recent times?

EDIT1:

Punarapi jananam, punarapi maranam... is Adi Shankara's assertion. Attainment of Mokasha is getting out of  this round and round  unending continuous circle. Verification of experience in a repeating circle and verification of advanced experiences guiding a Mumukshu into a higher spiritual orbit is part of the same total phenomenon. Those ahead  and graduated only can guide those who are new entrants.

Comment: It's not clear what you wanted to ask. Is your question about verification of rebirth, or about verification of freedom from rebirth? See the title of your question.

Comment: Verification of Moksha naturally includes that of re-birth

Comment: Can you be more clear? Do you want proof for Moksha or proof for rebirth? or do you say it's impossible to find proof for these things?

Comment: I went through linked comments by Tezz which touch my query more..It  is like the parents' assertion or if needed by foreign office a testimony about your birth, who your parents are etc, Perhaps a Guru's direct experience transmission. as he alone can convincingly hit the nail on its head...it is most essential in such matters. However, asking for birth certificate in the Registrar's office is not entirely blasphemous under some circumstances.